# Is code rate included in $E_{b}/N_{0}$ calculations when it increases message time?

Tags: digital-communications

I am seeking to calculate the individual sample SNR from a given $E_{b}/N_{0}$. I am calculating this as follows:

$E_{s}/N_{0} = E_{b}/N_{0} + 10\log_{10}(M)$
$SNR = E_{s}/N_{0} - 10\log_{10}(n)$

Where $M$ and $n$ refer to the bits and samples per symbol, respectively.

I am encoding with $R_{c}=1/2$, resulting in a total frame length which is twice as long in time. Explicitly, the transmission bandwidth remains constant.

Is it correct to not include $R_{c}$ in the above calculations? And if so, are there scenarios when it should be included?

Comment: In your displayed equation, the left side is $E_s/N_0$ while the right side is $E_s/N_0 - 10\log_{10}(n)$  which implies that $\log_{10}(n)=0$, i.e. $n=1$. Are you sure that this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

$E_b$ refers to "energy per **information** bit", so yes, you need to take the code rate into account. I don't know of an agreed upon notation, but I have used the following to relate the various quantities for $M$-ary modulation (e.g. BPSK is 2-ary, QPSK is 4-ary):

- $E_s$ = energy per symbol
- $E_c$ = energy per coded bit = $\frac{E_s}{\log_2{M}}$
- $E_b$ = energy per information bit = $rE_c$ = $\frac{rE_s}{\log_2{M}}$